# Abort Printing of Huge Amounts of Text in Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, signal

This has happened to me in a variety of instances:

- Sometimes I accidentally copy/paste the wrong thing into vim, and
  then I have to wait around 10 minutes for it to print through all
  that text.
- I would love the SQL extension of IPython, but because it doesn't seem to have a good way of returning large queries, again, I have to wait a long time after each query to go through all that text.

Surely, there has to be a way of interrupting that?

Comment: @Huey It is in Vim, so it will not work. At least it never works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> pauses sending any more text to the tty -- at which point you can (usually) do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send a SIGINT to the subprocess to stop it from printing.

That way, if you're in vim or IPython, you don't have to kill the process and can remain in your session.

Also, in the SqlMagic extension of IPython, you can prevent it from happening at all by setting `SqlMagic.displaylimit.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for me the scenario is, once it starts printing, it will not take in any inputs before it is done...